# JavaScript loses method when minified

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JavaScript file that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        clearCookies: clearCookies,
        setCookie: setCookie,
        getCookie: getCookie
    };
};

function getCookie(name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf('='));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf('=') + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        if (x === name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
    return '';
}

function setCookie(name, value, expiresInDays) {
    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + expiresInDays);
    var cookieValue = escape(value) + ((expiresInDays === null) ? '' : '; expires=' + expiryDate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = name + '=' + cookieValue;
}

function clearCookies() {
    setCookie('token', '', 0);
    setCookie('quoteDetails', '', 0);
    location.href = 'index.html';
}
```

Then in my **main.js** I have tried to do this:

```
var { checkPostCode } = require('epc_common');
var { getCookie, setCookie } = require('epc_cookies');

$('#quotemebutton').click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let storedToken = getCookie('token');

    /* ---- remove for brevity ---- */
});
```

I am using **Bable** to allow me to use es6, which generates a minified file. The problem is it is failing to invoke the **getCookie** method.

The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function

I would have thought that when it minified my code it would minify the require aswell as the invoking method?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        clearCookies: clearCookies,
        setCookie: setCookie,
        getCookie: getCookie
    };
};
```

you have a *single export*, which is a function, which, when invoked, returns an object. But in

```
var { getCookie, setCookie } = require('epc_cookies');
```

you're trying to retrieve the `getCookie` and `setCookie` functions without invoking the function that the `require` returns.

Export just the plain object instead, at the bottom of the file that exports:

```
module.exports = {
    clearCookies: clearCookies,
    setCookie: setCookie,
    getCookie: getCookie
};
```

Since it looks like you're using ES6, you can use shorthand property names:

```
module.exports = {
    clearCookies,
    setCookie,
    getCookie
};
```